# c# time out after executing connection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, connection, timeout

I have an application that connects to MS access and acquires data to show in my application. I want to setup a timeout after 2 minutes. Meaning, 2 minutes after the search button is executed that the connection to my access database is terminated.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the easiest way to accomplish this? Or a way to just close the connection after the data is acquired?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you mean this, A value of 0 indicates no limit, and should be avoided in a CommandTimeout because an attempt to execute a command will wait indefinitely.

```
this.Adapter.InsertCommand.CommandTimeout = timeout;
```

you can also add to connection string

```
Connection Timeout=2;
```